# WPF: Click Event Is Not Raised on Touch Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I cannot figure out why our touch devices does not work properly in new windows.

I have created an example that reproduce the error here:

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="touchTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="400" Width="400">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Integer}" FontSize="48" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Integer}" FontSize="48" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private int _integer;

    public int Integer
    {
        get => _integer;
        set
        {
            _integer = value;
            new DialogWindow().ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

**DialogWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window
    x:Class="touchTest.DialogWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Close" Click="OnClick" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**DialogWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class DialogWindow
{
    public DialogWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

When one of the textboxes has content changed, and you uses touch to focus the other textbox, the `DialogWindow` will pop up. Now the problem occurs, and we have to press (touch) the close button multiple times (etc. 9 times on one of our devices) before the click event happens and the dialog closes.

`TouchDown` event works properly. We're also experincing this on other elements than `Button`, for example `TextBox`. It is therefore not a solution to switch to `TouchDown` event. Everyhing in the new window seems to be buggy.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/2ks9gm/wpf_touch_input_broken_by_design_and_microsoft/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802030/419761

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/194

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Tunnelling TouchUp event like this:

```
<Button Content="Close" Click="OnClick" PreviewTouchUp="OnClick" />
```